# SQL "IF" expression coding

Tags: sql

Im using a program that uses SQL in the background and I have run into a snag and I just cant figure it out.

It has asked for a SQL Expression to calculate cost mark up in a data field.   I sort of get how it works because Ive used Excel and have done some complex calculations but SQL is different and I am having a hard time grasping it.  Anyway ...

I need to have the expression code say:

```
If column A is between   $0-$9.99   add 70% 
If column A is between  $10-$14.99  add 30%
If column A is between  $15-$24.99  add 21% 
If column A is between  $25-$89.99  add 14.9%
If column A is between  $90-$244.99 add 10%
If column A is between $245-$499.99 add 9%
If column A is between $500-1999.99 add 6.9%
If column A is         $3000 and up add 7.5 %
```

It should be all one string / expression

Also it should round to the 2nd decimal place.

If I am missing something or using the wrong wording forgive me -SQL newbie here

Please help me!!
Thank you

Comment: use 'cases' search for it

Comment: What database server are you using? Oracle, Mysql, mirco soft sql-server? There are small differences in the SQL syntax that will someone would need to know to be able to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "add xx%"?  Do you want something like `0.7` the portion to add?  `1.7` (the multiplication factor)?  Or `price * 1.7` (the final value)?

Comment: For someone to adequately answer this question we need the `RDBMS` you're using (as @RedCricket mentioned) and the `data type of column A` (e.g. is it a varchar that includes the $ or is it a decimal column)

Comment: What if it's between 2000 and 2999?

Comment: It is an mySql database located on a remote server.  I am using software on local windows PC that pulls in pricing data from a vendors server and I have to add statement to mark up cost. It does look like the Case statement is what I need to add the percentage amount but how that is accomplished, i have no clue, it is by either adding the percentage or multiplying  I think the "* 1.7" part looks right in the Case statement listed by Bohemian.  The end part of the statment I don't get  " else coulumnA
  end columnA_plus_tax" .  need it to round to 2 decimal palaces  ie: "10.25" no dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

Use a case:

```
select cast(
  case
    when columnA between 0 and 9.99 then columnA * 1.7
    when columnA between 10 and 14.89 then columnA * 1.3
    -- etc for other value ranges
    else columnA
  end as decimal(10, 2)) as columnA_plus_fee
```

Comment: It is an mySql database located on a remote server. I am using software on local windows PC that pulls in pricing data from a vendors server and I have to add statement to mark up cost. It does look like the Case statement is what I need to add the percentage amount but how that is accomplished, i have no clue, it is by either adding the percentage or multiplying I think the "* 1.7" part looks right in the Case statement listed by Bohemian. The end part of the statement I don't get " else coulumnA end columnA_plus_tax". I need it to round to 2 decimal palaces ie: "10.25" no dollar sign.

Comment: The `else` is for the default value in case no `when` conditions are true, and I have chosen to return the column unchanged in this case. The `end` is a required keyword to close the `case` statement. The `columnA_plus_tax` is the column name I gave to the result of the case result - name it as you like.

Comment: I have added a cast to make it have 2 decimal places